# Should I use common equity or total equity for book value? (when replicating Lewellen's 2015 paper on a cross section of expected stock returns)

Tags: equities, fama-french, ratio, crsp

I'd hereby would like to ask if any of you know whether I should use common equity or the total equity value, when computing monthly BM ratio's as done by Lewellen is his 2015 paper on a cross section of expected stock returns.

Full reference;
Lewellen, J. (2015). The cross-section of expected stock returns. Critical Finance Review, 4(1), 1–44. https://doi.org/10.1561/104.00000024

Accessible at;
https://faculty.tuck.dartmouth.edu/images/uploads/faculty/jonathan-lewellen/ExpectedStockReturns.pdf

I believe he is only looking at common stocks, yet at the same time to calculate the market value of equity I can only find the shares outstanding of all public shares on a monthly basis in CRSP.

Thank you in advance,

Kind regards, Julien Maas

Comment: "common stock" Would you share where it mentioned in the paper? Even he used only those data, his theory might be applied to preferred stock. Have you tried his equation on other than common stock?

Comment: Dear mr Cho, first  of all thank you for your response. On page 5 he states "My tests use all common stocks on the Center for Research in Security Prices (CRSP) monthly files, merged with accounting data from Compustat". He also states that the sample is all common stocks under most of the tables.

Comment: He does not specify, I think, what he takes to be the "book value of equity", On page 12, he states "some studies follow Fama and French (1992) and calculate B/M once a year" and then he says that his measure is computed at the beginning of each month.  If I look at Fama and French 1992, which has the same name as Lewellen's paper, on page 428, they mention that BE/ME is the ratio of the book value of common equity to its market value. And they define Market equity as (a stock price times shares outstanding) on page 427. So I am guessing this would be his definition as well.

Comment: I have not tried using a total value of book equity which includes preferred equity and other claims, since I am trying to use his methodology and apply it to a different dataset and set of signals. So in that sense it's not a  real replication which I am attempting, yet more of making use of the same methodology to examine a different set of signals. So there is no way that I can easily see, whether he used common equity or total equity by changing the variable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing additional information. It looks like that you want to try on different data.  What other method(s) did you check before choosing Lewellen's?

Comment: I have also tried using prior fiscal year end numbers to calculate the market value of common equity yet these were suboptimal, as they did not include the most timely data like in Lewellen. Most other studies that I looked at simply referred to "book value". Yet they often mention Fama and French. Another study that Lewellen mentions refers to book equity as "common equity per share" (Rosenberg et al, 1985).

Comment: Your question is still confusing to me. There is no suggestion from other after one week, I guess that you may narrow down (or make easier?) your question or the Lewellen's method is only for common stock.

Comment: I understand. I think I was just confused because of the shares outstanding variable in CRSP (SHROUT), which includes all outstanding public shares according to the description. So for this reason I posted the question here. So in essence to reword the question, it would be does it make sense to use common equity as the book value? Yet after I posted the question, and saw your comment, only then I noticed that in Fama and French 1992, they used the same variable to calculate the market value of equity while using common stock as the book value, so now I think that it does make sense.

Comment: Also because he doesn't specify it in the paper itself, and many papers do not specify what they mean by "book value" I was a bit confused. Since I thought that both the common equity and total value of equity could be described as the book value of equity.

Comment: I do not know how to close a question on this forum yet, yet I think the question is pretty much anwsered. Unless there's something I missed, I am assuming I can use common stock as the book value and the stock price times the shares outstanding of all public shares for the market value.

Comment: If you find an answer of your own question, you're welcome to post it. No problem of that. Example of answering own question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename. Your post might bring other's different suggestion.

Comment: That's a good idea! I'll post an answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though he does not state it explicitly, it is likely that he used the value of common equity as the book value of equity.

On page 12, Lewellen states "some studies follow Fama and French (1992) and calculate B/M once a year" and then he says that his measure is computed at the beginning of each month.

If we look at Fama and French 1992, which has the same name as Lewellen's paper, on page 428, they mention that BE/ME is the ratio of the book value of common equity to its market value. And they define Market equity as (a stock price times shares outstanding) on page 427.

Since he uses the shares outstanding from CRSP, and is only looking at common stocks. It makes sense that this would be his definition as well.

Moreover he refers to another study (Rosenberg et al, 1985) that used common equity per share as the book value of equity.

Comment: I fully agree. There's a standard way of calculating book value, see Fama and French (1992, 1993). You start with seq or ceq + pstk or at - lt (in that order of availability). You then add txdb and itcb and subtract preferred stock which is pstkrv or pstkl or pstk (in that order of availability). That is the standard definition. Unless it's explicitly stated otherwise, academics use something like this to calculate the book value of equity.